# Lagrange multipliers for tensor properties

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, computational-physics

Suppose a tensor has to be numerically consistent throughout simulation however due to uncertainty in taking derivatives etc elements of the tensor drift away from having required properties. How would I go about introducing a Lagrange multiplier to ensure the tensor remains normal $[E_{ij},E_{ij}^{*}]=0$. nb. It's evolving according to some free energy $F$.

Comment: "A tensor" is quite a vague indication. Assuming that your tensor is a function of the dynamical variables of simulation and that such simulation can be seen as a dynamical evolution, you may use or adapt to your problem the technique invented by Rckaert, Ciccotti and Berendsen (J.Comp. Phys 23, 327,1977). Although the method is interesting and originated in the community of physicists, I think this question is more suitable for the SE sites for Computational Science or Matter Modeling.